# Odoo does not load web.framework Javascript module in a custom addon

Tags: odoo

I want to add UI blocker functionality (which is implemented by Odoo team themselves in `web.framework` module) to an existing javascript file in my own addon.

Before my changes, the JS module was tested and is working fine.

As soon as I add the following line:

```
let framework = require('web.framework');
```

Odoo stops loading the module and reports in Chrome console:

```
warning: Some modules could not be started
Missing dependencies:     (1) ["web.framework"]
Non loaded modules:     (1) ["my_addon.my_js_module"]
```

When I activate developer mode in Odoo settings, I see that indeed browser loads many files from `addons\web\static\src\js\core` folder, except file `misc.js` where `web.framework` is defined.

I did Upgrade command on my module, I restarted Odoo, I tried developer and production modes and loaded the website with `Disable cache` setting - nothing helps, `web.framework` module is not loaded into my addon module.

The problematic js file also has other module dependencies:

```
let ajax = require('web.ajax');
let core = require('web.core');
```

and those are working fine. Only `web.framework` is breaking.

What's going on? How do I enforce loading of `web.framework`?

Initially, the problem was found in Odoo 13.0+e (Enterprise Edition). But for a clean test, I just tried a Bitnami Odoo Community v13 installation and Website app. I customized the JS code for the webiste and have the same issue. The JS module is not loaded anymore as soon as I add `var framework = require('web.framework');`